# How to add items into the list from other list using for each C# smart technique

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, foreach

Can I add list data from other list items using for each loop without extracting the method?
I want to add a new list to `PersDriver`.

Here is the code where `PersDriver` is a list of Test class and `AutoDrivers` is a list passing from the model. But I am getting an error at the end of the new PersDriver() {} that ; expected.
Can anyone correct my simple code without extracting a new method or add it to the list?

```
Test t1 = new Test(testModel model)
{
   PersDriver = new List<PersDriver>() 
   {
       model.AutoDrivers.ForEach(_driver =>
       {
           new PersDriver()
           {
               Id= _driver.Id,
               Name = _driver.Name
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just work if you fix the error the compiler is giving you? Add a `;` at the end of `new PersDriver() { ... };`

Comment: @arconaut I'm afraid that would still not be adding the `new PersDriver()` to the actual list `PersDriver`.

Comment: Ah, indeed, it seems so. But the `;` error or "extracting a new method" don't seem to have anything to do with the problem.
The easiest will probably be to go with `Select`, like in the answer of @SomeBody - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982078/81359

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try LINQ:

```
Test t1 = new Test(testModel model)
{
   PersDriver = model.AutoDrivers.Select(_driver =>
      new PersDriver()
      {
           Id= _driver.Id,
           Name = _driver.Name
      }).ToList()
};
```